# How to enable rich snippets using JSON-LD code for multi product pages?

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets, json-ld

I would like to make rich snippets for product pages appear in google SERPS. It's for a page that:

- Contains multiple products that each have individual prices
- Has an average aggregate rating

As far as I understand it's possible to add multiple products to one page in schema org using multiple offers. The problem is that I couldn't find the documentation on how to do that using JSON-LD. I've tried it myself in the code below but have no idea if this is correct. Can I just add offers like this or do I need to add them in a different way?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "Product",
"aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating", 
    "ratingValue": "[rating variable]",
    "reviewCount": "[count variable]"
},
"name": "[product name]",
"offers": {
    "@type": "Offer", 
    "price": "[price of product]",
    "priceCurrency": "[currency]"
},
"name": "[product name]",
"offers": {
    "@type": "Offer", 
    "price": "[price of product]",
    "priceCurrency": "[currency]"
},
"name": "[product name]",
"offers": {
    "@type": "Offer", 
    "price": "[price of product]",
    "priceCurrency": "[currency]"
},
}
</script>
```

Comment: Some of the quotation marks are wrong (`“` instead of `"`).

Comment: Thanks Unor. Sloppy mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just create an array of the offers.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "[name]",
  "image": "[logo]",
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "[rating],
    "reviewCount": "[votes]"
  },
  "offers": [{
    "@type": "Offer",
    "priceCurrency": "[currency]",
    "price": "[price]",
    "category": {
      "@type": "thing",
      "name": "[name product]"
    }
  },{
    "@type": "Offer",
    "priceCurrency": "[currency]",
    "price": "[price]",
    "category": {
      "@type": "thing",
      "name": "[name product]"
    }
  },{
    "@type": "Offer",
    "priceCurrency": "[currency]",
    "price": "[price]",
    "Category": {
      "@type": "thing",
      "name": "[name product]"
    }
  }]
}
</script>
```